# Autosys job scheduling with date_condition and condition

Tags: autosys

I'm trying to do such scheduling:

- JOB_A starts on it's own calendar (possibly every day?) and do somehing. It's already configured.
- JOB_B should be started right after JOB_A but only on every friday. I need to configure this job.

So the questions are:

1. How autosys works when i define date_condition with start_times and conditions?
2. Any way to define date_condition without start_times and start_mins?
3. How to define JOB_B? JOB_A ends at 7.52-7.53 every day. I cannot use calendar, it's pain to make new one because of burocracy and processes. I don't have time for this :\

I tried to do this, but has no results:

```
date_condition: 1
start_times: "7:00, 8:00"
condition: s(JOB_A)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule JOB_B to run only on Fridays, have it start at the same time as JOB_A, and make it dependent on JOB_A. This way, Autosys will start it at e.g. 07:00, check its conditions, and see that JOB_A is still running, causing JOB_B to wait for JOB_A to finish.

Assuming JOB_A is already set up and running at 07:00, JOB_B would need to be configured like this:

```
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: fr
start_times: "07:00"
condition: s(JOB_A)
```